# How can I translate this URL into a Graph API search or FQL query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can find all users who like StackOverflow and live in California using this URL on Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/search/1462865420609264/likers/union/108131585873862/residents/present/intersect

I've been trying to get the same results using the Graph API and FQL for hours but haven't been able to get the response I'm looking for. The data is there, and I can clearly access it on Facebook itself. How can I query this data outside of Facebook using either the Graph API or FQL?

I just need the user's `uid`.

Comment: You can always build a crawler for this.

Answer (score 3):

> The data is there, and I can clearly access it on Facebook itself.

That does not mean it must be freely available via API as well.

> How can I query this data outside of Facebook using either the Graph API or FQL?

You can’t. Graph API offers [very limited search functionality](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search).

Graph Search (what you get via the search box on facebook.com) is not exposed via API, because it would be just too powerful a tool to acquire huge amounts of personal data, do all sorts of profiling on that, etc.

Graph Search is deliberately exposed to human users only, and not via API.

> I just need the user's uid.

You won’t get it. User privacy is more important than what you need.

---

The “but I can see it on facebook.com” argument is not valid here – because in that context it is about what *you* can see, whereas when this information was queried via API, a 3rd party (the app developer) would get their hands on this as well.